# Maven release:perform hangs at maven-site phase

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

currently I try to perform a mvn release:perform but it hangs when it came to the maven-site phase.

Here is the log in debug mode till it hangs

```
[INFO]     Using credentials from server id 'maven-site'
[INFO] [DEBUG]  configureWagon
[INFO] [DEBUG] configureWagon server snapshots
[INFO] [DEBUG] configureWagon server releases
[INFO] [DEBUG] configureWagon server maven-site
[INFO] [DEBUG] configureWagon server release.server
[INFO] [DEBUG] configureWagon server svn.srs-pen.de
[INFO] [DEBUG] repository protocol scp
[INFO] [DEBUG] getProxy 'protocol': scp
[INFO] [DEBUG] getProxy 'protocol': scp no ProxyInfo found
[INFO] [DEBUG] Mapped url: scp://release.server/srv/www/htdocs/foo.bar
/foobar-module/4.1.4/foobar-module/ to relative path: ..\..\..\foo.bar\foobar-
module\4.1.4\foobar-module
[INFO] [DEBUG] top distributionManagement.site.url=scp://release.server/srv/ww
w/htdocs/foo/parent/1.23/, actual module relative path: ../../../de.s
rs.pen.foobar/foobar-module/4.1.4/foobar-module
[INFO] [DEBUG] Mapped url: scp://release.server/srv/www/htdocs/foo.bar
/foobar-module/4.1.4/foobar-module/ to relative path: ..\..\..\foo.bar\foobar-
module\4.1.4\foobar-module
[INFO] [DEBUG] authenticationInfo with id 'maven-site': mvnsite
[INFO] [DEBUG] connect with authenticationInfo and without proxyInfo
[INFO] Using private key: C:\Users\foouser\.m2\playground-mvnsite.ppk
[INFO] The authenticity of host 'release.server' can't be established.
[INFO] RSA key fingerprint is e9:49:9c:c7:2b:02:dd:a8:4e:04:09:8f:e7:eb:03:ef.
```

The distriubution is configured like this

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://release.server/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://release.server/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <site>
        <id>maven-site</id>
        <url>scp://release.server/srv/www/htdocs/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a ssh connection to the release.server as well? Or just http connection? I guess maven site is using ssh to copy the doc.